# Convert a Character String with commas into a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I am looking to convert a character vector:

```
text <- "MY, NAME, IS, SLIM, SHADY"
```

into a character vector:

```
vector <- c("MY", "NAME", "IS", "SLIM", "SHADY")
```

This seems so easy, but for some reason I can't get something like this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `scan`

```
newvec <- scan(text = text, what ="", sep=",", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
newvec
#[1] "MY"    "NAME"  "IS"    "SLIM"  "SHADY"
```

---

Or with `strsplit`

```
unlist(strsplit(text, ",\\s*"))
```